# Stop Keypress event at end of scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, keypress, scrollto

I'm using scrolTo plugin to create a long vertical page which you scroll to each new post on click or a key press.

Here's the layout:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
    <div class="entry"></div>
</div>

<div id="controls">
    <span class="prev">UP</div>
    <span class="next">DOWN</div>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
function scrollToPosition(element) {
    if (element !== undefined) {
        $('html, body').scrollTo(element, 500, {
            margin: true
        }); 
    }
}
$(function() {
    var posts = $('.entry');
    var position = 0;
    var next = $('.next');
    var prev = $('.prev').hide();
    next.click(function(evt) {
        prev.fadeIn();
        scrollToPosition(posts[position += 1]);
        if (position === posts.length - 1) {
            next.fadeOut();
        }
    });
    prev.click(function(evt) {   
        next.fadeIn();
        scrollToPosition(posts[position -= 1]);
        if (position === 0) {
            prev.fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       $('.next').click();
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
       $('.prev').click();
    }
});
```

Every thing works except for when using the key-press. Once you've got to the bottom if I hit down (next) 5 times. I would have to hit up (Prev) 5 times plus 1 more time to actually go up. I know the logic behind why this is happening but I don't know the solution to stop it. I need to indicate an end to the keypress.

Thanks

--

FINAL CODE:

```
    $(function() {
    var posts = $('.folio');
    var position = 0;
    var next = $('.next');
    var prev = $('.prev').hide();
    next.click(function(evt) {
        prev.fadeIn();
        scrollToPosition(posts[position += 1]);
        if (position === posts.length - 1) {
            next.fadeOut();
        }
    });
    prev.click(function(evt) {   
        next.fadeIn();
        scrollToPosition(posts[position -= 1]);
        if (position === 0) {
            prev.fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 40 && next.is(":visible")) {
            next.click();
            return false
        } else if (e.keyCode == 38 && prev.is(":visible")) {
            prev.click();
            return false
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: could you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) as your problem is not immediately obvious without context?

Comment: It seems like you're actually binding click events on keydown rather than calling them.  This doesn't make sense to me; you should be triggering them, right?

Comment: Thank you! I changed it accordingly. Hasn't solved prob but much neater. What you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the visibility of next/previous in the keydown event:

```
if (e.which == 40 && next.is(":visible")) { ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?.. I'll get a fiddle up to make it easier to demo

Comment: Ah, realise what your saying. Going to try it out.

Comment: Explosion Pills: Thanks this worked a treat. So simple it hurts. I've added the finished code for folks. Cheers. Aside: Going to look at scroll events now!